# Plotting $2^x+2^y=2^x$ on Desmos

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software, implicit-function

When I plot $2^x+2^y=2^x$ on Desmos, I get this graph:
[image]

But I think it should not plot anything at all, since $2^y=0$ does not have a solution for $y$.

**Can someone guess what happened on Desmos's side? Or is it something only the developers know?**

Comment: Desmos isn't perfect. I had some strange polar equations Desmos couldn't handle correctly either. But when you contact them you may get a good answer. They did I my case.

Comment: Happens with base $e$ too. Stepladder pattern.